# Writing Pure HTML in Jade

Tags: webgl, pug

Jade appears to choke on WebGL shader/fragment blocks when writing in Jade format, so I would like to write them as straight HTML while still being able to write Jade around it. Is this possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These:

```
html
    body
        | <h1>Title</h1>
        | <p>foo bar baz</p>
```

compiles into:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <p>foo bar baz</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

hope it helps