# Output php directly into a jade template

Tags: php, pug

I have a jade template that needs a bit of php to populate a checkbox. The below code works fine if the checkbox needs to be checked but I need to remove the attribute completely if $options['virtual-host'] is not set. How can I add a raw attributes to a element without jade trying to help me out?

```
 input(type="checkbox",name="options[virtual-host]",value="1",id="virtual-host",
   checked!="<?php echo ( isset( $options['virtual-host'] ) 
   && $options['virtual-host'] ) ? 'checked' : '';?>")
```

The end output needs to look something like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="options[virtual-host]" value="1" 
  id="virtual-host" <?php echo ( isset( $options['virtual-host'] ) 
  && $options['virtual-host'] ) ? 'checked' : '';?>/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Check these: [Writing Pure HTML in Jade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16404582/writing-pure-html-in-jade/16405934?noredirect=1#comment23630753_16405934)

```
| <input type="checkbox" name="options[virtual-host]" value="1"  id="virtual-host" <?php echo ( isset( $options['virtual-host'] )  && $options['virtual-host'] ) ? 'checked' : '';?>/>
```

Should work, but not sure.

Why dont try a pure jade/js solution? Im not feeling too good with these php there.

Comment: This also works with pure-PHP blocks; just prepend each line of the block with a `| ` (including the first and last lines, `| <?php` and `| ?>`).